# Notation for the space of eventually-zero sequences

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, vector-spaces

An *eventually-zero sequence* is a real-valued sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ for which  there exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n=0$ for each $n\geq N$. The space of eventually-zero sequences equipped with the sup-norm is usually denoted by $c_{00}$. I am working with the same underlying set of sequences, but in my case it is equipped with the $\ell^1$-norm. Is there any established notation for this space of sequences?

Comment: c_{00} or c_{00}(\mathbb{N}) is just a vector space it is not the convention that it is equipped with the sup-norm.

Comment: @KevinBeanland Thanks very much. That's a relief, because I like the notation $c_{00}$ for this space.